# How to get objects who have votes from model in Django?

Tags: django

I'm creating a system to rating comments of a video for example like youtube that you can vote 'like or dislike' (1,0 with a BooleanField) for comments and these will appear at the top if the count of likes is the bigger, I know how to get the comments of a video and show them, but my problem is when I try to get the comments with the votes for each one:

I have these models:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    #and more things

class Comment(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    video = models.ForeignKey(Video)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class RatingComment(model.Model):
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    vote = models.BooleanField()
```

So in my views, I can get the comments of a video with:

res = Video.objects.get(alias__exact=something)

coms = Comment.objects.filter(video=res)

Then I make a render_to_response to the template with this values. But I need to get the comments with the count of like and dislikes.

¿How can I create that?

Answer (score 0):

Use [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) Queryset modifier:

```
Comment.objects.select_related('ratingcomment_set').extra(
    select={
        'likes': 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM applabel_ratingcomment WHERE applabel_ratingcomment.comment_id = applabel_comment.id and applabel_ratingcomment.vote = 1'
        'dislikes': 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM applabel_ratingcomment WHERE applabel_ratingcomment.comment_id = applabel_comment.id and applabel_ratingcomment.vote = 0'
    },
)
```

Comment: +1. With a different data model one could just use annotate: http://www.djangofoo.com/182/filter-annotate-count